# Parallel processing in perl to write array entries to db

Tags: arrays, database, perl, parallel-processing

I have a program written in perl (Perl Version 5.10.1 running under Linux) that generates an array. Each entry of the array is another array. Each of these last arrays contains a set of 7 values that I need to write to a database. Currently I run a loop over the array of arrays and write the info to the database. As these writes are independent of each other I was thinking that I could run several processes in parallel.

Below is the basic loop I currently use that I would like to split into parallel processes. I need to do this in parallel as the initial array of arrays contains around 100,000 entries, which takes about 30 minutes to add the entries to the database.

```
for my $icell (0 .. scalar @Sheet_Cells_Data-1){
    my $Cell_Data_INTER1=$Sheet_Cells_Data[$icell];
    my @Cell_Data=@$Cell_Data_INTER1;
    $insert_to_db->execute($Cell_Data[0],$Cell_Data[1],$Cell_Data[2],$Cell_Data[3],$Cell_Data[4],$Cell_Data[5],$Cell_Data[6]);
}
```

So, would this be possible and if so how would I go about achieving it.

Any help much appreciated

Chazg76

Comment: What database do you use? It's possible that it supports "bulk load", which is usually the fastest possible way to load data. In such a case, you can use Perl to transform the data into the supported format, and then run the bulk load.

Comment: Pretty fundamentally though - if the database is doing the 'work' then parallelising the script isn't going to help.

Comment: Just as a side note, Perl 5.10.1 was released in 2007, that will make the version 10 years old.

Comment: Another point to look at might be the (auto)commit setting. If possible, try to set `autocommit` to false and then commit every 1000th row or so. Often that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using SQLite?  In this case you may find this useful https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

If you are using DBI.pm, you can speed up inserts by preparing the insert statement once with placeholders, then executing multiple times

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(“insert into table values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)”);
for my $icell (0 .. $#Sheet_Cells_Data){
    my $Cell_Data_INTER1=$Sheet_Cells_Data[$icell];
    my @Cell_Data=@$Cell_Data_INTER1;
    $sth->execute(@Cell_Data[0]);
}
```

I find this provides some speed up, but is much faster (hundreds-thousands of times faster) to follow choroba's suggests and write the data to a tab delimited file and load with

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/user/data/table.tsv' INTO TABLE db_table
```

which is highly optimized for most RDBMS

make sure to give a complete path for the input file as the default is usually a privileged directory used by the RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this parallel processing is using fork.
Something like below

Let's say we will make 5 parallel process to do the insert work. Here is the code:

```
my $max_proc   = 5;
my $batch_size = scalar @Sheet_Cells_Data / $max_proc;
my $start_point = 0;

for (1 .. $max_proc) {
    if (fork()) {
        #In Parent
        $start_point += $batch_size;
    } else {
        #In Child
        my $end_point = $start_point + $batch_size -1;
        for my $i ($start_point .. $end_point){
           #Do you insert work here
        }

        exit;
    }
}
```

Few points to take care:

```
1. Wait for all the child process to finish before parent process ends.
2. You might have to initialize new database connection in each child and close them before child process ends.
```